# iOS 13 Crash with SwipeKeyboard and textfield:shouldChangeCharactersIn:

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios13

In iOS 13, when implementing `shouldChangeCharactersIn` via the `UITextfieldDelegate`, the application crashes when using the swiping keyboard.

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if let text = textField.text as NSString? {
            let txtAfterUpdate = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            textField.text = txtAfterUpdate
        }
        return false
    }
```

Is this an Apple bug?

Comment: Which line causes the crash? What is the error? Are you sure it's actually a crash? Sometimes the debugger hits breakpoints on its own. Try clicking the "continue" icon (possibly a few times).

Comment: If you debug your code, you'll see that the app crashes because it goes into an infinite loop. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @DonMag What loop do you mean? Setting the `text` property of a UITextField programmatically does not result in a call to `shouldChangeCharactersIn`.

Comment: I don't know what's going on "under-the-hood" but it's definitely causing an infinite loop. Add `print(range, text, txtAfterUpdate)` before `textField.text = txtAfterUpdate` and watch the debug console. My ***guess*** would be that the swipe keyboard inserts the text and then tries to decide what word was meant... and that triggers another `shouldChangeCharactersIn` call.

Comment: @rmaddy - forgot to tag you in the above comment...

Answer (score 5):

I was able to reproduce this - if you mutate the state of the text on a UITextField during swipe entry - and only during swipe entry, it'll attempt to reinsert the swiped content (even if you return false), which retriggers your delegate event, which kicks off the recursive cycle.

It's a bit of a hack but you could catch it with something like

```swift
    private var lastEntry: String?

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string.count > 1 && string == lastEntry { // implies we're swiping or pasting
            print("Caught unwanted recursion")
            return
        }
        lastEntry = string
        if let text = textField.text as NSString? {
            let txtAfterUpdate = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            textField.text = txtAfterUpdate
        }
        return false
    }
```

It'll stop users from pasting/swiping the same thing twice in a row, but at least it'll let them swipe while Apple fixes their problem.

Comment: I'll file a radar and add a link once I get to it.

Comment: how's your radar? @mcornell

Comment: How can I do it in OBJC?

Answer (score 2):

I used UIPasteboard to identify when the user is pasting and then leave the text as the user entered using the swipe like this:

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                      shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                      replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    //check if the user used swipe keyboard
    if string.count > 1 && string != UIPasteboard.general.string ?? "" {
        return true
    }
    //do the text treatment
    return false
}
```

I also realized that the TextField only accepts static strings when using swipe keyboard.
Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 2):

When you use slide-to-type for text typing, don't mutate a text value in `textField.text` before the method returns a boolean value.
To fix the issue, let's explore the example below to uppercase inputed text:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
               shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
               replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let currentText = textField.text as? NSString else {
        return true
    }

    // Second step: change a text value after
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        textField.text = updatedText.uppercased()
    }

    // First step: don't change the text in text field
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before setting text you can reset delegate and after set it to self again.
But this solution has one problem if textfield is empty - text will be doubled.

Му code example:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let currentText: String = textField.text ?? ""
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        textField.delegate = nil
        let resultText = editedText
        textField.text = resultText
        if currentText.isEmpty, textField.text != resultText {
            textField.text = resultText
        }
        textField.delegate = self
    } else {
        textField.text = input.result
    }
    return false
}
```